# Custom Content Type iFrame

Tags: magento2.4.2, page-builder

I am building a Page Builder Custom Content Type that will allow a user to enter in a URL and have the URL content display in an iFrame. Is this possible?

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_vendor_module_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd" extends="pagebuilder_base_form">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pagebuilder_vendor_module_form.pagebuilder_vendor_module_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Catalog Page View</item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <namespace>pagebuilder_vendor_module_form</namespace>
    <deps>
        <dep>pagebuilder_vendor_module_form.pagebuilder_vendor_module_form_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<dataSource name="pagebuilder_vendor_module_form_data_source">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataProvider name="pagebuilder_vendor_module_form_data_source" class="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\ContentType\DataProvider">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName/>
            <primaryFieldName/>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
<fieldset name="appearance_fieldset" sortOrder="10" component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/dependent-fieldset">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Appearance</label>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__fieldset-visual-select-large">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
        <collapsible>false</collapsible>
        <opened>true</opened>
        <imports>
            <link name="hideFieldset">${$.name}.appearance:options</link>
            <link name="hideLabel">${$.name}.appearance:options</link>
        </imports>
    </settings>
    <field name="appearance" formElement="select" sortOrder="10" component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/dependent-visual-select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">default</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
                <class name="admin__field-visual-select-container">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <elementTmpl>Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/visual-select</elementTmpl>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="AppearanceSourceCatalogLayout"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="catalog-one" sortOrder="20">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Catalog One</label>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <opened>true</opened>
    </settings>
    <field name="catalog_one_title" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataScope>catalog_one_title</dataScope>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Catalog Title</label>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-string" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <urlInput name="catalog_one_link" sortOrder="30">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Issue Link</label>
            <dataScope>catalog_one_link</dataScope>
            <urlTypes class="Magento\Ui\Model\UrlInput\LinksConfigProvider"/>
        </settings>
    </urlInput>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/vendor_module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd">
<type name="vendor_module"
    label="Catalog Layout"
    menu_section=""
    component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type"
    preview_component="Vendor_Module/js/content-type/vendor-module/preview"
    master_component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/master"
    form="pagebuilder_vendor_module_form"
    icon=""
    sortOrder="23"
    translate="label">
<children default_policy="deny"/>
<parents default_policy="deny">
    <parent name="row" policy="allow"/>
    <parent name="column" policy="allow"/>
</parents>
<appearances>
    <appearance name="default"
              default="true"
              preview_template="Vendor_Module/content-type/vendor_module/default/preview"
              master_template="Vendor_Module/content-type/vendor_module/default/master"
              reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/read/configurable">
    <elements>
            <element name="main">
                <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                <style name="border" source="border_style" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-style"/>
                <style name="border_color" source="border_color"/>
                <style name="background_color" source="background_color"/>
                <style name="background_image" source="background_image" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/background-image" preview_converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/preview/background-image"/>
                <style name="border_width" source="border_width" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-width"/>
                <style name="border_radius" source="border_radius" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/remove-px"/>
                <style name="margins" storage_key="margins_and_padding" reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/margins" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/margins"/>
                <style name="padding" storage_key="margins_and_padding" reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/paddings" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/paddings"/>
                <style name="display" source="display" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/display" preview_converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/preview/display"/>
                <attribute name="name" source="data-content-type"/>
                <attribute name="appearance" source="data-appearance"/>
                <css name="css_classes"/>
            </element>
            <element name="catalog_one_title">
                <html name="catalog_one_title" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/html/tag-escaper"/>
            </element>
            <element name="catalog_one_link">
                <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                <attribute name="catalog_one_link" reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/link" persistence_mode="read"/>
                <attribute name="virtual_link_href" storage_key="catalog_one_link" source="href" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/attribute/link-href" persistence_mode="write"/>
                <attribute name="virtual_link_target" storage_key="catalog_one_link" source="target" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/attribute/link-target" persistence_mode="write"/>
                <attribute name="virtual_link_type" storage_key="catalog_one_link" source="data-link-type" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/attribute/link-type" persistence_mode="write"/>
            </element>
        </elements>
    </appearance>
</appearances>
</type>
</config>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/content-type/vendor_module/default/master.html

```
<div attr="data.main.attributes">
<div class="catalog-menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cat-title-1" class="catalog-title" data-catid="1">
        <span
            attr="data.catalog_one_title.attributes"
            ko-style="data.catalog_one_title.style"
            css="data.catalog_one_title.css"
            html="data.catalog_one_title.html">
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="catalog-1" class="catalog-view active">
    <div style="position:relative;padding-top:max(60%,326px);height:0;width:100%"><iframe allow="clipboard-write" sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-downloads allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" allowfullscreen="true" style="position:absolute;border:none;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;" if="data.catalog_one_link.attributes().href" attr="data.catalog_one_link.attributes" ko-style="data.catalog_one_link.style" css="data.catalog_one_link.css"></iframe></div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, your element needs a converter to be defined, e.g.:

```
<html name="catalog_one_link" converter="My_Module/js/converter/iframe"/>
```

The converter is a JS class that needs to provide 2 methods: fromDOM and toDOM - it is used to convert the raw input (e.g. the url in your case) into a DOM element (and back when editing the content type again).

You could either let the converter render the iframe directly or do that in a widget and let the converter add the widget call to the output.

Maybe the architecture overview of PageBuilder helps a bit to understand the concept: https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/architecture/overview.html